# Ascmd tool clamis database already exists however it does not appear

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, ascmd

I'm trying to create OLAP DB via analysis services in SQL Server 2008 with ascmd.exe tool
I get the following error:

> Error ErrorCode="3239313410" Description="Errors in the metadata man
>   ager. The database with the name of 'CosmoComOLAPDB' already exists in
>   the 'LIOR2K8' server." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Analysis
>   Services" HelpFile="" />

However, when I connect to the Analysis Services in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, I can't find it...

Is it common issue or just on my system?

**Update:**
When I'm trying to Attach and then choose a folder it gives me the following error:

> Database Administrator or server administrator permissions are
>   required to execute SystemGetLogicalDrives command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason i could not see the database is because I was not running in administrative mode
Right Click on SQL Server Management -> Run As Administrator
Then the Analysis Database will appear

Answer (score 0):

it may exist but not be attached.

Right click on the database folder and click attach.

Select the folder from the list and inform the password, if existing

Comment: You need to run Management Studio with highest lever permission.